# Degeneracies in linear combination of tensor product of Pauli matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, na.numerical-analysis, matrix-analysis

Let $P_i \in \{I,X,Y,Z\}^{\otimes n} $, that is $P_i = \bigotimes_{i =1 }^n \sigma_i$ with $\sigma_i \in \{I,X,Y,Z\}$, where

$$
I = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \hspace{1cm} X = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \hspace{1cm} Y = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -i\\ i & 0 \end{pmatrix} \hspace{1cm} Z = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}
$$

Let $H$ be a Hermitian matrix in $\mathbb{C}^{2^n} \times \mathbb{C}^{2^n}$, then $H$ can be expressed as

$$ H = \sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i P_i \hspace{1 cm} \alpha_i \in \mathbb{R} $$

Now, is it possible to come up with the structure of $P_i$ which makes sure there is no degeneracy (duplicate eigenvalues) in the eigenvalues of $H$?

*I ran a bunch of numerical simulations but can't find any pattern for it, but this might be a well-known fact.*

Comment: To clarify: are you asking for a (large) subset of the $P_i$'s with the property that, for all $\alpha_i$, $H$ does not have duplicate eigenvalues?

Comment: @NathanielJohnston Yes, that's right.